# AddRangeAsync xunit MockQueryable.Moq error

Tags: c#, moq

The actual result always return 0 while testing method `AddRangeAsync` by `MockQueryable.Moq`.Any ideas on this?
Thanks!

#### Running on:

- .net core 3.1
- MockQueryable.Moq 5.02
- xunit 2.4.0

#### Service

```cs
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private readonly MyDb _myDb;

        public ProductService(MyDb myDb)
        {
            _myDb = myDb;
        }

        public async Task AddRange()
        {
            var products = new Product[]
            {
                new Product { Id = 1, Count = 2, Name = "Apple", Price = 24 },
                new Product { Id = 2, Count = 14, Name = "Banana", Price = 13 },
            };
            await _myDb.Products.AddRangeAsync(products);
            await _myDb.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

#### Test Code

```cs
        [Fact]
        public async Task AddRangeTest()
        {
            var initProducts = new List<Product>();
            var mockProducts = initProducts.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
            mockProducts
                .Setup(x => x.AddRangeAsync(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Product>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Callback((IEnumerable<Product> products, CancellationToken _) => initProducts.AddRange(products));
            var mockDb = new Mock<MyDb>();
            mockDb.Setup(x => x.Products).Returns(mockProducts.Object);

            var productService = new ProductService(mockDb.Object);
            await productService.AddRange();
            // the actual always return 0
            Assert.Equal(2, mockDb.Object.Products.Count());
        }
```

#### Result

Message: 
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 2
Actual:   0

Comment: Here is the way Microsoft recommand:[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database?source=recommendations).It said "As discussed in the testing overview page, using the in-memory provider for testing is strongly discouraged; consider using SQLite instead, or implementing the repository pattern."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way [Microsoft recommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database?source=recommendations):

> As discussed in the testing overview page, using the in-memory provider for testing is strongly discouraged; consider using SQLite instead, or implementing the repository pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`mockDb.Object.Products` is just a mock, hence `Count()` returns the `default` `int` until you make a `Setup()` for it.

Also I'd wager that `initProducts.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();` will create a `DbSet` that is *not* tied to `initProducts`. So the whole idea of your test seems impossible to me.